# Ideals and Filters are closed under Arbitrary intersection and Arbitrary union respectively

Tags: general-topology, ideals, filters

I just realised two things.

> $1)$ Ideals are closed under arbitrary intersection.
>
> $2)$ Filters are closed under arbitrary union.

$X$ is a set.$I\subset \mathcal P(X)$ is called an **Ideal** if the following are satisfied.

$i)\Phi\in I$

$ii)A,B\in I \implies A\cup B\in I$

$iii)B\subseteq A, A\in I \implies B\in I$

Now take an arbitrary collection of members of $I$, say, $\mathcal A=\{A_i:i\in \Lambda , A_i\in I \forall i\}$ and let $C=\bigcap_{i\in \Lambda}A_i$ then $C\subset A_i\forall i\in \Lambda$ and hence $C\in I.$

$F\subset \mathcal P(X)$ is called a filter if the followings are satisfied

$i)\Phi \notin F$

$ii)A,B\in F \implies A\bigcap B\in F.$

$iii)A\in F, A\subseteq B\implies B\in F$

Now in the same manner as above take an arbitrary collection of members of $F$,say, $\mathcal B=\{B_i:i\in \Lambda,B_i\in F\forall i\in\Lambda \}$ and $D=\bigcup_{i\in \Lambda}B_i$ then $B_i\subseteq D\forall i\in \Lambda$ hence $D\in F.$

Thus my claims are proved.

And if $F=F(I)$,i.e. the dual filter of $I$ then the result about $F$ follows directly from the result about $I.$

$1$ and $2$ easily follow from the definitions but apparently the converse is not true (at least I don't see it being.)

Thoughts please. Thank you.

Comment: The converse is indeed not true. If $X$ is a set with at least two elements, $\{S\subseteq X:|S|\le 1\}$ is a subset of $\wp(X)$ that is closed under arbitrary intersections but is not an ideal, because it’s not closed under finite unions. The family of complements of these sets is closed under arbitrary unions but is not a filter, since it’s not closed under finite intersections.

Comment: Care to make it an answer, @Brian? If not, I'll gladly make a Community Wiki version.